# Execute remote PowerShell script from VSOnline fails - Access Denied

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-virtual-machine, powershell-remoting

I am facing a very strange issue trying to run a Remote PowerShell script from the new build system of Visual Studio Online.

**Context:**
I have a Build server that I host on my own VM. I have also created a second VM where I want the PowerShell script to be run on.
When I run a build from the Build server, I want to create a task that run a PowerShell script on a remote machine. Sounds easy.
Both machines have everything configured to run the Remote PowerShell. (I think)

**Problem:**
If I manually run the script from the build server, the script is properly executed on my remote machine.
But, if I run the script by starting a new build, it doesn't work, I always get an error message

> New-PSSession : [xxx.cloudapp.net] Connecting to remote server xxx.cloudapp.net failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

Have you faced this issue before with VSOnline?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if there isn't a trust relationship between the remote machine and the build machine. E.g. you could look at the hosts.equiv file on the remote machine and make sure it trusts the build machine.

If that doesn't help then more info might be needed, like how you're trying to sign in, what build agent account you're running as.

- Guy